# Working with ContentProvider to get Thumbnail image

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-contentprovider, mediastore

I try to get thumbnail image and put it into my layout. I have fragment class with onCreateView method.

```html
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      
        cr = getActivity().getContentResolver();
        image = new ImageView(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        String[] mProjection = {
                MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID
        };
        thumbnails = cr.query(
                MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                mProjection,
                null,
                null,
                null);

        if (thumbnails==null){
            Log.d("yerchik/fragment", "error");
        }else if (thumbnails.getCount() <1){
            Log.d("yerchik/fragment", "nothing returned");
        }else {
            Log.d("yerchik/fragment", "thumbnails returned");
            thumbnails.moveToFirst();
            int index = thumbnails.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID);
            Log.d("yerchik/fragment", "index: " + index);
            if (thumbnails.moveToNext()){
                Random r = new Random();
                int rand = r.nextInt(thumbnails.getCount());
                thumbnails.moveToPosition(rand);
                bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(
                        cr,
                        thumbnails.getInt(index),
                        MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND,
                        null);
                image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }
        }
        return image;
    }
```

So here I get thumbnail images. I have set permissions in manifest file:

```html
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

and in my main activity i put this fragment as follows:

```html
Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.addBtn);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                fm = getFragmentManager();
                ft = fm.beginTransaction();
                BlankFragment fragment = new BlankFragment();
                ft.add(R.id.thumbnailsGridLayout, fragment);
                ft.commit();
            }
        });
```

In my logs i have:

thumbnails returned

so i got some thumbnails, but nothing appears.

Interesting thing is that if I add layout for fragment and declare my ImageView with some src image and comment out image.setImageBitmap(bitmap) line i will get my sample image drawn. After I delete comment nothing appears, so it seems that my code draws something, because image added from layout disappears, but no thumbnail appears.

Answer (score -1):

MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail() got deprecated.

Try using loadThumbnail().

Like this (in Kotlin) :

```
val cr = applicationContext.contentResolver
val bitmap = cr.loadThumbnail(uri,Size(25,25),null)
image.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
```

Comment: cr.loadThumbnail(uri,Size(25,25),null) require api 29+. What's your/Google solution to that? As far as I can tell, nobody is using 29 on google play.